# Product of two polish spaces

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces, then $X \times  Y$ is Polish in the product topology.
I know the result of the product of a number of spaces, I have already demonstrated that it is separable but when I want to see that it is metrizable it is where I do not know how to define the metrics that the topology generates and matches the product, for the countable case it is used the one convergent sum but in this case, what would it be?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: $\sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2}$ for example. Choose $d_1$ and $d_2$ to be complete metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_X$ be a complete metric for $X$ and $d_Y$ be a complete metric for $Y$.

Then $d:=\max(d_X,d_Y)$ (really $d((x,y), (x',y'))= \max(d_X(x,x'), d_Y(y,y'))$ is a metric for $X \times Y$ that generates the product topology as

$$B_d((x,y),r) = B_{d_X}(x,r) \times B_{d_Y}(y,r)$$

and open balls form bases for metric spaces. Completeness of $d$ is a simple exercise and if $D$ is dense in $X$, and $E$ dense in $Y$, $D \times E$ is dense in $X \times Y$. Countable times countable is countable etc.

Comment: It my be worth pointing out that there are other metrics that also work, like the $\sqrt{d_X^2+d_Y^2}$ in a comment under the question or $d_X+d_Y$, but that the metric in this answer, $\max(d_X,d_Y)$, has the advantage of giving an easier proof that the induced topology is the product topology.